# Can anyone identify this possibly Czechoslovak uniform?

Tags: military, identification, weapons, uniform, czechoslovakia

I have this photo of my Great Grandfather Antonin Hošek and his wife Elisabeth Hofrichter with my Grandma as a baby Alzběta Hošková. I am trying to find out more about my family's past and I'd love to know if anyone can identify this uniform? Where from? What is the rank? etc. It is most likely to be Czechoslovakian around 1926. [image: h]

I also have a knife and sheath from him. New photos attached.[image: Antonin Hošek's military knife 1926] [image: Antonin Hošek's military knife 1926-2]

I also have a certificate - can anyone transcribe it for me, please? [image: Antonin Hošek Medaili Vítézství]

Comment: The hat looks [Czech](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Delostreleckyvycvik-005-sw-lay.jpg).

Comment: I think it is most likely Czech. If it is, can you identify the regiment?

Comment: OK Thank you. I will have to ask my mother for the original photo and scan it at a better resolution to see if there is any more clarity or detail. I will post again once I have this.

Comment: Thank you, kimchi lover. Do you know a department in the Czech Republic that I could email to find out more?

Comment: @kimchilover I've added a military knife image which was also my Great Grandfather's if that gives any clues.

Comment: @TomasBy I've added a military knife image which was also my Great Grandfather's if that gives any clues.

Comment: @kimchilover I think you should start using the other box on this page…? [Rotmistr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rittmeister) is unclear how you arrived at that, but the rest looks quite good to go?

Comment: @LаngLаngС I've found that Rotmistru is a variant of the word Rotmistr because it is awarded "to" someone. Part of Czech Grammar known as pády.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Thanks!  I've never looked at Czech paradigms before.  I suppose we are talking about dative singular, and Antonin and Hošek take different shapes in this case?

Comment: @kimchilover I've found him on the Czech Central Military Archive. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DWL  Super!  Glad to have been of help.  I hope you will be able to share some of what you learned here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This summarizes my since-deleted comments into a slightly more coherent form.
It is only a partial answer to the originally posed question, and relies on the photographs the OP added after their original post.
The uniform is Czech; the bearer was at some point an NCO.

The cap badge has the overall shape of a tilted square containing a smaller square region, as does the badge of the [Czechoslovak army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovak_Army), as illustrated on the cited wikipedia article.   The image on the knife hilt matches this badge: this is indeed a Czech uniform & gear.

The diploma, or certificate, is the award of a "Victory Medal", as illustrated on various vendors' and collectors' pages (such as [this](https://www.collectorsweekly.com/stories/35465-the-wwi-victory-medal-series--czechoslo), which has an explanatory essay) and history blogs, for example,
[this one](https://forum.axishistory.com/viewtopic.php?t=234305).  This last item transcribes and explains some of the text on a similar certificate.  At the end of World War I all allied veterans were given a Victory Medal by their governments.  The case of Czechoslovakia was different, because there was no such country during the war, even though many of its future citizens fought on the allied side in what was called the [Czechoslovak Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovak_Legion), whose name predates the creation of the Czechoslovak Republic.
After the Republic was founded a Czech version of the victory medal was created, and apparently awarded to your great grandfather.  At that time he was presumably in the Czech army, as evidenced by the uniform and repetition of the badge on the hilt of the knife.

One of the web sites above translates another person's diploma reading

> President of the republic of Czechoslovakia
> Number of decret

> to Captain of rus.(sian) legions
> ?V.? Hladky

> As per Minister of Nationals Defence’s proposal
> I award you
> The medal of Victory

> To rememberance of your part
> in world’s war for civilisation.
> This medal was vindicated by your volunteer
> entry into Czechoslovak
> foreign corps.

> In Prag 8th December ?1922?

> Minister of national defence (empty)

> (Signature is of President T. G. Masaryk, 1st Czechoslovak President)

The handwritten bits of your diploma are the certificate number "2574", what I read as "rotmistru franc legii", the name "Antoninu Hoszovi" (in what I suppose is an inflected form  of your grandfather's name: I do not know Czech), and at the bottom the date "15 zari 1922", (that is, 15 Sept 1922) and the president's signature "T. G. Masaryk".

Another site mentioned above explains "war for civilization" means the Great War, which we now call "World War I".  The only problematic item is the line with rank and service.  There was a French branch of the [Czechoslovak Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovak_Legion#Legion_in_France), analogous to the Russian branch mentioned on the other certificate.  So "franc legii" is understandable.  The rank seems to say "rotmistru" which seems to be an inflected form of a [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranks_of_the_Czechoslovak_Armed_Forces) for  sergeant major, a kind of senior NCO.  (The word itself is probably derived from German [Rittmeister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rittmeister), meaning cavalry captain.)  It's not clear to me if that refers to his war-time rank or to his 1922 rank.

The [web page](http://www.uniforminsignia.org/?option=com_insigniasearch&Itemid=53&result=480) gives rank insignia for ceremonial uniforms in the period 1925-1929.  A rotmistr's epaulette had a row of plants snaking its length, and a single round "pip" at the end farthest from the button by the neck.  What I see in the portrait photo is what looks like a twisted braid running the length of the epaulette ending with a single pip of indistinct shape.  This is consistent with rotmistr, but if the pip is actually a narrow rectangular bar or a rotated square, the rank changes.

Comment: This is such a great help, thank you. I have emailed the Czech Ministry of Defence so will see if they have any records of it. I'm really grateful for all the information and links to other websites. Hopefully, I can start to uncover more of my family's past.

Comment: Could you somehow relate the diploma written *rotmistru* to the rank displayed in the photo more clearly? The shoulder boards do say *something* (which is what I can't discern on its own, but mixing & matching might narrow it down a bit further.

Comment: @LаngLаngС I just added a para about this.  I cannot see detail in the photo well enough to be sure.

Comment: "rotmistru franc. legií Antonínu Hoškovi" is literally "to rotmistr of the French legion Antonín Hošek" (Czech singular dative case). The year is definitely 1922.

Comment: I don't have the rep to add an answer, so just some remarks: It looks fairly likely that the uniform is of a "rotmistr" (sergeant major), as there seems to be just a single round "pip" on the side of the cap. The badge on the front of the cap clearly shows that he was in a non-combat ("service") unit, combat units had two crossed swords sticking out from the badge ([see picture here](http://www.1-prapor-sos.wz.cz/sos/csa/cepice.html)). The exact [kind of the unit](http://www.1-prapor-sos.wz.cz/sos/csa-barvy_vylozku.html) (e.g. administration, engineers, logistics, etc.) is hard to tell in B&W.

Comment: @TooTea  Thanks for the comment.  I did not know that the lack of crossed swords was significant, nor that ranks were also shown on the side of the cap.

Comment: Why do you say, that the German Rittmeister is an NCO rank, when the wikipedia link you provided clearly states, that it is a commisioned officer rank equivalent to Hauptmann or Captain (OF-2 in the NATO order). The wikipedia page seems to indicate, that all other forms of Rittmeister are also of the same rank.

Comment: @Dulkan  Basically, ignorance.  Thanks for the correction. Since corrected. In the Czech army nowadays, Rotmistr is OR-5, even though Rittmeisters are officers in Germany.